# systemd: nginx does not resolve /etc/hosts entries at boot time

Tags: systemd, nginx, init-script

Using Debian 9, the behaviour of systemd is the following:

- At boot-time nginx does not seems to read `/etc/hosts` and failed to start
- After boot, when the command `systemctl start nginx` it is working properly

Note: the file `/etc/hosts` is correct and remains untouched during all the tests.

After searching for a while, I tried to start `systemd-resolved` before nginx. There is no impact.

> Oct 13 11:14:01 server-dev systemd-resolved[466]: Positive Trust Anchors:
>   Oct 13 11:14:01 server-dev systemd-resolved[466]: . IN DS 19036 8 2 49aac11d7b6f6446702e54a1607371607a1a41855200fd2ce1cdde32f24e8fb5
>   Oct 13 11:14:01 server-dev systemd-resolved[466]: . IN DS 20326 8 2 e06d44b80b8f1d39a95c0b0d7c65d08458e880409bbc683457104237c7f8ec8d
>   Oct 13 11:14:01 server-dev systemd-resolved[466]: Negative trust anchors: 10.in-addr.arpa 16.172.in-addr.arpa 17.172.in-addr.arpa 18.172.in-addr.arpa 19.172.in-addr.arpa 20.172.in-addr.arpa 21.172.in-addr.arpa 22.172.in-addr.arpa 23.172
>   Oct 13 11:14:01 server-dev systemd-resolved[466]: Using system hostname 'server-dev'.
>   Oct 13 11:14:01 server-dev systemd-resolved[466]: Switching to system DNS server 192.168.1.1.
>   Oct 13 11:14:01 server-dev shorewall[465]: Compiling using Shorewall 5.0.15.6...
>   Oct 13 11:14:01 server-dev systemd[1]: Started Network Name Resolution.
>   Oct 13 11:14:01 server-dev systemd[1]: Starting A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server...
>   Oct 13 11:14:01 server-dev systemd[1]: Reached target Multi-User System.
>   Oct 13 11:14:01 server-dev systemd[1]: Reached target Graphical Interface.
>   Oct 13 11:14:01 server-dev systemd[1]: Starting Update UTMP about System Runlevel Changes...
>   Oct 13 11:14:01 server-dev systemd[1]: Started Update UTMP about System Runlevel Changes.
>   Oct 13 11:14:01 server-dev nginx[502]: nginx: [emerg] host not found in upstream "server-dev.com" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:33
>   Oct 13 11:14:01 server-dev nginx[502]: nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
>   Oct 13 11:14:01 server-dev systemd[1]: nginx.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
>   Oct 13 11:14:01 server-dev systemd[1]: Failed to start A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
>   Oct 13 11:14:01 server-dev systemd[1]: nginx.service: Unit entered failed state.
>   Oct 13 11:14:01 server-dev systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

I found a working solution, it is linked to *nginx proxy configuration*.
I am not clear about the impacts, feel free to comment or propose a better solution.

1. Install dnsmasq
2. Add a domain name resolver in nginx configuration

> server {
>     # redirect DNS requests to local dnsmasq
>     resolver 127.0.0.1;
>   
>     # without these 2 lines, nginx does not resolve name correctly
>     set **$mt_proxy_from** "http://server-dev.com:8000";
>     set **$mt_proxy_dest** "https://server-dev.com";
>   [...]
>     location / {
>         # Proxy configuration
>         proxy_pass          **$mt_proxy_from**;
>         proxy_read_timeout 90;
>         proxy_redirect     **$mt_proxy_from** **$mt_proxy_dest**;
>     }}

I don't like this solution because it seems not efficient:

- Install dnsmasq and add a resolver to nginx sounds OK
- Add NGINX dynamic variables to resolve the names dynamically (not clear when?) seems weird because the local addresses are fixed

Question: is there any way to do something *clean*?

- Configure the IP addresses in `/etc/hosts`
- Make NGINX resolve the names according `/etc/hosts` at systemd boot time?

Sources:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8305015/when-using-proxy-pass-can-etc-hosts-be-used-to-resolve-domain-names-instead-of
https://www.jethrocarr.com/2013/11/02/nginx-reverse-proxies-and-dns-resolution/